# Drop In Reputation - But No Record Of Why?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I know that there are various reasons for rep dropping suddenly.

What I am asking is, can the reason be recorded permanently in your reputation change history, even if - for example - an upvote was reversed. If people are trying to improve and track reputation to see what things work and what things get a negative response, losing points without knowing why isn't helpful.

If you downvote something, that negative change to your rep gets recorded - can withdrawn / reversed / otherwise cancelled changes also be recorded, please? I would just like to understand what happened when it does happen.

This was triggered by me suddenly losing 15 pts - I assume an accepted answer of mine was withdrawn or possibly reversed - but for what question?

Comment: For -15 it already says "unaccept". IIRC it says "serial upvoting reversed" in the case o serial upvoting. There's also "unupvote"/"Undownvote"

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately nothing appears to be recorded against my account for the sudden change today (1329 to 1314 - Stack Overflow, about 3pm) - the only negative (so far, he says pessimistically!) was a -1 for downvoting something. Is it possible there's a bug? Or possibly it was an adjustment / recalc by a mod and those don't get recorded?

Comment: It could also be that you answered someone's question and their account was deleted (deleting all of their questions as well)... I'm pretty sure that's how it works.

Comment: @M.Babcock - understood. Is it feasible to also record changes due to such actions? I would like to think that *any* change could be recorded, no matter what the reason, but I do accept that there are limits on what can reasonably be done without a significant code change!

Comment: Such actions actually should be recorded already. If you scroll down to the bottom of your reputation history tab, there should be a checkbox labeled "show removed posts". Checking that may reveal the source of the drop.

Comment: @Jeremy - thank you. I did already find and set that, but it revealed nothing :(

Comment: Was it really necessary to change the paragraphing of the question? That really is petty.

Comment: @JTeagle I was tempted to do the same. It's more readable now than it was as a solid block of text. Everybody edits everybody here; you shouldn't be offended.

Comment: If anything, be thankful. Some people (like me) simply don't read things that are hard to parse and many will often downvote _just for that reason_

Comment: @M.Babcock Deleting an account doesn't necessarily delete their questions... it really depends on the delete reason.  For example, my (now deleted) Gaming account shows all its questions, answers, and comments attributed to user2974.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920662/insert-text-to-selected-textbox-use-javascript/9920711#9920711) was accepted then unaccepted many times in the same day (ultimately with no net rep change), here's a full history:

```
AnswerUnaccepted    2012-03-29 13:49:56Z   -15
AnswerAccepted      2012-03-29 09:46:30Z    15
AnswerUnaccepted    2012-03-29 09:46:22Z   -15
AnswerAccepted      2012-03-29 09:23:02Z    15  
AnswerUnaccepted    2012-03-29 09:23:01Z   -15
AnswerAccepted      2012-03-29 09:23:00Z    15  
AnswerUnaccepted    2012-03-29 08:38:01Z   -15
AnswerAccepted      2012-03-29 08:37:52Z    15
```

You don't see it because we don't show this do/undo behavior because...well, it'd be obnoxious.

Comment: Would it make sense to only show the do/undo behavior once to avoid this confusion?

Comment: @M.Babcock - I really don't think it's worth complicating it *even more* to handle this case, since that's just other confusion

Comment: I agree with M.Babcock - a one-line record stating that credit was given and then removed (resulting in a net change of 0) would be nice, but I do see the logic. I'd also like to know what individual did that so I can go shake them by the... er... hand. That's a pretty mean thing to do to someone who tried to help them.

Comment: @NickCraver - You're probably right, besides it probably doesn't happen often enough to justify a special case for it.

Comment: @M.Babcock Note: you would see that "behavior" on your reputation page seen on the mobile version of Stack Overflow.